# Redefine macro from outside its defining file

Tags: c, macros

"redefining" a macro, that has already been defined in another header file, to control the behavior of, lets say, the functions using it.

An example would make things more clear.

```
/* foo.h */
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#ifndef MAX_LEN
    #define MAX_LEN 256
#endif

void foo();

#endif
```

the function `foo()` just prints the value of the macro defined in the header

```
/* foo.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

void foo()
{
    printf("%d", MAX_LEN);
}
```

When I run the following code, I will get the output `256`

```
/* main.c */
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Now, what I want is to change `MAX_LEN` from inside of `main.c` so that I would get a different result

```
/* main.c */
#define MAX_LEN 16
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is still `256` and not `16`? How can that be?

[Also read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34056649/redefine-macro-from-outside-its-defining-file#comment55867924_34056778)

Comment: I think you are overwriting the MAX_LEN value using foo.h in your code

Comment: @nullpointer That's what the `#ifndef` is for. It's not doing that.

Comment: @nullpointer how come? if `MAX_LEN` is defined before I ever include `foo.h`, then the line where it says `#ifndef MAX_LEN` will fail, thus the preprocessor will skip the next line which holds the default value for that macro. At least this is how I see it

Comment: @Jonas @iharob `#define MAX_LEN 16
#include "foo.h"` here i meant..in main.c

Comment: @nullpointer maybe I wasn't clear. I want to overwrite the macro so I could get `16` as the output but I'm not getting that

Comment: Macros are a simple text replacement. `main.c` doesn't expand `MAX_LEN` anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `MAX_LEN` that matters is the one that *foo.c* sees when it is compiled.  It doesn't matter how it is defined in *main.c*.  The only way to modify what is printed from within `foo` is to define `MAX_LEN` when you compile *foo.c*.  Usually something like `gcc -DMAX_LEN=16 -c foo.c` will do the job.

In other words, you cannot affect the *foo.c* compilation unit from within *main.c*.

Comment: I used to use `kiss_fft` library to compute simple FFT on a set of floats. But when the set is of integers, I just define `#define FIXED_POINT 32` before the  `#include "kiss_fft.h"` line. This way the macro `kiss_fft_scalar` used in `kiss_fft.c` would be of type `int32_t` instead of `float`. ?? Either this or I have been wrong for a long time. I could look at the implementation of this library and say that the author of it used this exact trick to accomplish exactly this. There's even a comment saying `defines kiss_fft_scalar as either short or a float type`

Comment: I don't see any magic going on in the kiss fft code.  If _kiss_fft.c_ is compiled without `FIXED_POINT` being defined, then the object code is going to expect and manipulate structures of `float` regardless of how you define it when you include _kiss_fft.h_ in your code.  Are you compiling _kiss_fft.c_ with the same `FIXED_POINT` macro setting when you compile your code or are you using it as a precompiled library?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `foo.c` file is preprocessed before the files are linked together. This means that it's compiled with `MAX_LEN` set to `256` and when `main.o` is linked to `foo.o` it was already compiled like this

```
void foo()
{
    printf("%d", 256);
}
```

This is the result of (*without `#include <stdio.h>`*)

```
gcc -E foo.c
```

---

```
# 1 "foo.c"
# 1 "<interno>"
# 1 "<línea-de-orden>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<línea-de-orden>" 2
# 1 "foo.c"

# 1 "foo.h" 1
# 9 "foo.h"
void foo();
# 3 "foo.c" 2

void foo()
{
    printf("%d", 256);
}
```

So when it's compiled it's compiled as it is because you are not including the "*foo.c*" file in "*main.c*".

Comment: @Jonas I am not! I am saying that if you include it, it would be preprocessed with `main()` and `MAX_LEN` would be `16` when `foo()` is compiled.