# Redefining a Macro across header files

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, macros, preprocessor

I'm trying to (re)define a configuration macro I have set.
Here is an example of what I want to do:

```c
/* inc/foo.h */
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef FOO_CONF_MACRO
    #define FOO_CONF_MACRO 0
#endif

void foo(void);

#endif
```

```c
/* src/foo.c */
#include "foo.h"

void foo(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", FOO_CONF_MACRO);
}
```

```c
/* inc/bar.h */
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

#include <stdio.h>

#define FOO_CONF_MACRO 3

#include "foo.h"

void bar(void);

#endif
```

```c
/* src/bar.c */
#include "bar.h"

void bar(void)
{
    printf("Bar!\n");
}
```

```c
/* app/main.c */
#include "bar.h"

#ifndef FOO_CONF_MACRO
    #undef FOO_CONF_MACRO
#endif
#define FOO_CONF_MACRO 18

#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the following output from compiling all files and running `main.c`:

```
18
Bar!
```

However, what I actually observe is:

```
0
Bar!
```

Or, if I do not redefine the macro in `main.c`, I would expect:

```
3
Bar!
```

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34056649/6155242), which is very similar.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34056778/6155242) in particular makes it sound like this depends on the order in which the files are compiled and linked.
I share OP's sentiment though that I have seen this construct multiple times already to realize configuration macros in code you compile yourself. So does this really depend on the compile and link order? If so, what would be the correct order to get the desired output?

Currently, I have got the following in a makefile:

```
### app/Makefile

INCLUDES = $(wildcard ../inc/*.h) #/**/

CFLAGS := -O2 -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu99 -I. -I../inc

### build targets
all: main

### modules
## submodules
obj:
    mkdir -p obj

obj/%.o: ../src/%.c $(INCLUDES) | obj
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS)

## main program
obj/main.o main.c $(INCLUDES) | obj
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

main: obj/main.o obj/bar.o obj/foo.o
    gcc $< obj/bar.o obj/foo.o -o $@
```

When I observe the output from my `make`, it seems like `main.o` is generated first, then `bar.o`, and then `foo.o`.

Comment: Why do you have `#endif` in `bar.c` and `main.c` ?

Comment: Sorry, those were copy-paste errors

Comment: If you don't know about the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), now is a very good time to learn about it.

Comment: I'm aware of translation units. But the way I understood it (and the way the wiki article reads), the contents of foo.c and bar.c would roughly be pasted in place of the corresponding includes in my main.c. Do my macros get resolved before that happens? If so, what would be the correct way of using configuration macros? As I said before, I have seen this construct a couple of times before and they seem to work fine.

Comment: Here are two examples I've seen which use these configuration macros: https://github.com/ETHZ-TEC/LWB-Baseline/blob/master/arch/platform/sky/dev/glossy.h and https://github.com/olafland/chaos/blob/master/contiki/core/dev/chaos.h
Is the (re)definition supposed to happen within the same files instead of outside of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source files (`foo.c`, `bar.c` and `main.c`) together with their included *header* files are three separate translation units, without any connection to each other. Header files are really unrelated to any similarly named source file.

If you change the macro in one translation unit directly in the source file then no other translation unit will know about it.

If you change the macro in a header file, only the translation units where the header file is included will know about it.

Since `foo.c` only includes `foo.h`, it will know only about the macro from that header file.

Comment: Ah, I see where my misunderstanding was then. Do you have a recommended alternative to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @Lithimlin If you want the same value in all translation units, add the macro to the build flags in your `Makefile` using `-DFOO_CONF_MACRO=123` (for example). Otherwise I recommend you refactor your code to use function arguments instead.

Comment: Would it (theoretically) work if I had a `config.h` which I included in all of my source files where I do the configurations? I have already refactored my code but I was curious if this was a possibility in general